# How to find least dates of each month from given set of dates

Tags: java, sorting, date

I need to extract least dates from given dates array for every mentioned month.

example- date format is dd/MM/yyyy
Following is sample input

```
04/11/2019,  11/11/2019, 18/11/2019, 25/11/2019, 02/12/2019, 09/12/2019, 
06/01/2020, 03/02/2020, 10/02/2020, 17/02/2020, 24/02/2020, 02/03/2020, 
09/03/2020, 16/03/2020, 23/03/2020, 30/03/2020, 06/04/2020, 13/04/2020, 
20/04/2020, 27/04/2020
```

I need to get least date from each month:

output be like-

```
04/11/2019, 02/12/2019, 06/01/2020, 03/02/2020, 02/03/2020, 06/04/2020
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not able build logic for same. Not getting exact solution.

Comment: Don’t put your dates into a list of `String`s in the first place. Put them into a list of `LocalDate`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
public List<LocalDate> filterDates(List<LocalDate> dates) {
    return dates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YearMonth::from))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(Collections::min) // .map(Collections::max)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Instead of `.map(Collections::min)` you can use the following:

```
.map(list -> {
    list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    return list.get(0);
})
```

Or:

```
.map(list -> list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just by changing " return list.get(list.size()-1)" it gives me last date of each month from list which solved by second problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Note that `list.sort(...)` may throw an exception depending on the type of list returned by `groupingBy`. Using `list.stream().sorted()...` may be safer and more future proof.

Comment: You don’t need to sort the entire inner list to find the min (or max). Use for example `.map(Collections::min)`.

Comment: @assylias I would prefer `list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder())` instead.

Comment: @ruslanys Is it possible to do the same operation using HashMap<String,LocalDate> instead of List<LocalDate>?

Comment: @Tinks_say sure

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Java-8 you can use :

```
List<LocalDate> collect = Stream.of(strings)
        .map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, format)) // convert your strings to LocalDate
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YearMonth::from)) // group by year and month
        .values().stream()
        .map(a -> a.stream().sorted().limit(1).findFirst().get())
        .sorted()
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect the results
```

outputs

```
[2019-11-04, 2019-12-02, 2020-01-06, 2020-02-03, 2020-03-02, 2020-04-06]
```

[**Ideone demo**](https://www.ideone.com/9Iuxxm)

Comment: Your answer text is not complete (e.g. how to build the format object). Why dont't you post the exact code from the (working) demo?

Comment: Actually, there is no guarantee, that `map(a -> a.get(0)` will return the last date. And sorting after makes no sense. But the example is good. I made almost the same.

Comment: @Volokh my answer not for the way to parse the strings, in the demo I used a trick to just get the dates, the OP should have a list of strings

Comment: @ruslanys I agree with you for the first one, I edit it now, for the last sorted you need it to get the same expected result of the OP :) no need to dv when you make a comment :)

Comment: @YCF_L You made a mistake again :) Now you are fetching the earliest date per month. You should change `a.stream().sorted()...` with `a.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

Comment: And I didn't get what `dv` is in your comment `no need to dv when you make a comment :) `

Comment: mister @ruslanys did you check the outputs of the OP and the outputs of my answer? when I make `.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())` I get `[2019-11-25, 2019-12-09, 2020-01-06, 2020-02-24, 2020-03-30, 2020-04-27]` my output are `[2019-11-04, 2019-12-02, 2020-01-06, 2020-02-03, 2020-03-02, 2020-04-06]` the same as the OP :)

Comment: What did you explain the outputs of the OP a mistake? I agree with you, to get the last date in month you have to inverse your dates, but what you explain the outputs of the OP?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know why, but I thought that the issue is to find the latest dates per month and not earliest. Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @YCF_L now, when your code works, I removed my DV :) And what `OP` is?

Comment: @ruslanys OP means Original Poster, the person who share the question in this case :)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not worked for me. It was giving me string list as it is like original input string list

Comment: @Tinks_say did you checked the demo?

Comment: yes @YCF_L i tried it at my end. It was giving input string list as it is.

Answer (score 3):

There’s a wealth of good answers already. On top of those I would like to add:

1. Don’t put strings in your original list. Put `LocalDate` objects. If you get string input, parse it before adding to the list.
2. You don’t need to sort the inner list to get its minimum (or maximum).

**In Java 10 or later:**

```
    List<LocalDate> input = List.of(LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 4), 
            LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 11), LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 18),
            LocalDate.of(2019, 11, 25), LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 2),
            LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 9), LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 6),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 3), LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 10),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 17), LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 24),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 2), LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 9),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 16), LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 23),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 30), LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 6),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 13), LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 20),
            LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 27));

    List<LocalDate> minDatePerMonth = input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YearMonth::from, Collectors.minBy(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(Optional::orElseThrow)
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am using the overloaded version of [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) that accepts a *downstream collector*. `groupingBy` produces a map, but instead of the map values being lists they are produced by the downstream collector. In this case [`Collectors.minBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#minBy(java.util.Comparator)), which produces [`Optional<LocalDate>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html). And since the `groupingBy` would not create a map entry without at least one date, we know that the `Optional` cannot be empty.

Of course we want nicely formatted output for our user. We produce that in this way:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    String output = minDatePerMonth.stream()
            .map(formatter::format)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    System.out.println(output);
```

> 04/11/2019, 02/12/2019, 06/01/2020, 03/02/2020, 02/03/2020, 06/04/2020

**In Java 9**

The no-arg `Optional.orElseThrow` was introduced in Java 10. In Java 8 and 9 you may use for example:

```
            .map(old -> old.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("This can’t happen")))
```

**In Java 8**

`List.of` was introduced in Java 9. However you said that you had already got the list, so I consider how to initialize it outside the question. I trust readers to find their way of initializing it in Java 8 if required.

Comment: Hi Ole, nice answer, I think you don't need `map(Optional::orElseThrow)`, the grouping should always return at least a value, No

Comment: I need some way to unwrap the `Optional`, @YCF_L. I like `orElseThrow` (from Java 10) better than `get`. They work the same. You are right, the exception will never be thrown.

Comment: Why Java 10? What part of this code is not supported by Java 8 or 9?

Comment: @BasilBourque I believe the no-arg `orElseThrow` was introduced in Java 10. In Java 8 or 9 use either `get` or a lambda with the 1-arg `orElseThrow`. `List.of` is from Java 9, but on Java 8 you can surely find a way to initialize the list.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have edited and added the necessary change for Java 8 or 9. Thanks for the inspiring question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sequence that you will need to do

1. Parse your Strings to [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
2. Build a map where your key would be a month and your key would be a sorted List.

   3. Go through all the Lists and take the first value from each one

This is your algorithm. I will leave the implementation for you.

Answer (score 1):

//localDates is list of LocalDate. You can convert it.

```
localDates.stream().forEach(localDate -> {
            Integer month = localDate.getMonthValue();
            if (localDateMap.containsKey(month)){
                if(localDate.isBefore(localDateMap.get(month))){
                    localDateMap.put(month,localDate);
                }
            }else{
                localDateMap.put(month,localDate);
            }
        });
```

Then get all values from map.

Comment: Since you only use `getMonthValue()`, this will group dates from March 2019 with dates from March 2020 and only keep the earliest of those, that is, one from 2019 (in this example).

Comment: And as a detail, don’t use a stream. Just `localDates.forEach`, etc.